# How to use IdentityServer with docker-compose?

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, yaml, blazor-server-side

Ciao,
I'm developing one web application with these three components:

- **IdentityServer**: using IdentityServer4
- **Web API**: using ASP.NET Core 5
- **Web App**: using ASP.NET Blazor (server side).

I'm working in Windows with Docker for Desktop version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88.

I would debug and deploy my application's components as Docker containers. For each component I've added a Dockerfile and I've added to solution support for docker-compose.

Each Dockerfile expose the ports 80 and 443.

```
...
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
...
```

My docker-compose file is following:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapp
    ports: 
    - "44382:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApp/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - identityserver
        - webapi
    networks:
      - internal

  webapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi
    ports:
    - "44305:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApi/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - identityserver
    networks:
        - internal

  identityserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}identityserver
    ports:
    - "443:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IdentityServer/Dockerfile
    networks:
        - internal

networks:
  internal:
```

I've configured Web App with IdentityServer using these two packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="5.0.2" />
```

And these configuration:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Adding my dependencies...
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            // Temporarly I've disabled HTTPS but it doesn't let work the project
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
         
            options.Authority = Configuration["OpenID:Authority"];
            options.ClientId = Configuration["OpenID:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["OpenID:ClientSecret"];
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.Scope.Add("WebApi");
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.UsePkce = true;
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnAccessDenied = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("/");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });

        services.AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
    }
```

I start the application by Visual Studio 2019 using docker-compose. When I try to start the application I obtain one error like following:

> SocketException: Connection refused
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError
> error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> HttpRequestException: Connection refused
> (identityserver:443)
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func<SocketsHttpConnectionContext,
> CancellationToken, ValueTask> callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint,
> HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)
>
> IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from:
> 'System.String'.
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string
> address, CancellationToken cancel)
>
> InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration
> from: 'System.String'.
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
> cancel)

*****Note**: I can access correctly to Home Page of IdentityServer accessing directly by url with its port.***

I'm sure that the client is correctly configured because previously to use containers authorization work correctly.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you a lot

Comment: FYI, the `EXPOSE` instruction is documentative only, unless running with the `-P` flag. When specifying ports like you have its meaningless and doesn't offer any information of value

Comment: Hi Pinkfloydx33, thanks for your comment. The ports are correctly binded, because I can access to IdentityServer by browser. Now, I will edit the question.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, just an informational comment letting you know that you don't need to provide that information to *us* or even to docker

Comment: "The problem is that when I try to start the application" - where exactly do you start which application? It sounds as if you try to start it on the host system (outside of docker, e.g. Visual Studio). Outside of docker hostname "identityserver" is not available.

Comment: "I'm sure that the client is correctly configured" I'd double check that. An internal hostname can't work with additional configuration. How should your browser redirect to "identityserver" during oidc flow?

Comment: Hi Christoph, I've forgotten to say that I start the application by Visual Studio using docker-compose, now I update the question. About the configuration of the client, I know that outside docker the hostname is not reachable, I've tried to updated HOST file adding a rule for identityserver --> localhost but I think that the problem happen previously when the OIDC Client try to get the "well-know configuration". Thanks

Comment: The issue most likely has to do with https certificates. I've found this blog with does a nice job explaining why: https://mjarosie.github.io/dev/2020/09/24/running-identityserver4-on-docker-with-https.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao,

my problem was not related about docker but was caused by HTTPS. I suspect using alias I've invalidate development HTTPS certificate generated by Visual Studio.

I've checked this adding these lines of codes for each component (identity server, web api and web app) and using HTTP protocol:

```
if (!env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
```

Navigating in HTTP and changing Identity Server configuration I can view login page.
This is not a final solution but let me check that the problem was related about HTTPS certificate.